# ASP.NET 4.0 web form Routing on IIS 6.0 windows server 2003

Tags: routes, webforms, iis-6

I'm trying to run the web form routing in asp.net 4.0 on IIS 6.0 but I keep getting the 404 page.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute
       ("testRoute", "test/{param}", "~/testing.aspx");
}
```

in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
   <add name="UrlRoutingModule" 
        type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
              Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
   <add 
     name="UrlRoutingHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode" 
     verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" 
     type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,  
          Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
```

And I also tried to set the wildcard mapping for the site.
Path = C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
Unchecked the "verify that file exists"

Any clue on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: IIS 6 ignores `<system.webServer>`

Comment: Hi - did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Im doing the same thing on XP (IIS6) but without those web.config module and handler settings. I believe those are for AppFabric setups or something else.

At the bottom of my create routes I also have:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Default", "", "~/Default.aspx", false);
```

for the default page. This may be what your needing too.

Also check in the add/remove windows components in IIS to see if Routing is checked.